# Mongo Aggregate $and in $match Not Returning Results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having trouble trying to figure out why this aggregate is not returning results.

I am trying to find duplicates on a certain date. When I do a find I can see that multiple results are returned:

```
db.getCollection('transfers').find({createdAt: { $gte: ISODate('2018-07-09') }, dupField:'123456'})
```

Returns 4 results.

But when I try an aggregate it never returns results.

```
var g = db.transfers.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: { dupField: "$dupField" }, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
  { $match: { 
      $and: [
          { "count": { $gt: 1} },
          { "createdAt": { $gte: ISODate('2018-07-09') } }
      ]
  }},
  { $sort: { "count": -1 }}
])
print(g)
```

The aggregate works when I do not use the `createdAt` in the `$match` but when I add the `createdAt` in the `$match` it does not work.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You lost the `createdAt` field in the `$group` stage

Comment: don't know what you are trying to do here but `$match` condition should be the first stage in the pipeline as I can see then you can use `$group` stage... And you have to use either `$first` or `$push` to use your `createdAt` field at the `$match` stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo's aggregation framework consists of stages and each stage transforms the document as it passes through the pipeline.

In your case, there are two stages

1. the first stage of your pipeline is to group the document.

   `{ $group: { _id: { dupField: "$dupField" }, count: { $sum: 1 }}}`
2. then you pass over this groups to the second stage of your pipeline where you match `createdAt` and `count`.

But that won't work cause after stage 1 your document will get transformed and look
like this

`{
_id : 123456, // your dupField 
count:987 
}`

at second stage you don't have access to `createdAt`.

If you want to filter it based on `{ "createdAt": { $gte: ISODate('2018-07-09') } }` move it to the stage one i.e. before you perform the `$group` phase of the pipeline

Which would look something like this.

```
var g = db.transfers.aggregate([

{ $match: { "createdAt": { $gte: ISODate('2018-07-09') } } }, 

{ $group: { _id: { dupField: "$dupField" }, count: { $sum: 1 }}},

{ $match: {  "count": { $gt: 1} } },

{ $sort: { "count": -1 }}
])
print(g)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/